# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect on kafka set up

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have downloaded kafka binary version and after extracting in C drive, I used the following command in Windows to start zookeeper:
C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

But I got the follow error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Kafka isn't tested on windows, so without more debugging information, we cannot know what the error is referring to, for your specific system. For example, what version of Java do you have? Where is it installed? By the way, latest version of Kafka, does not require Zookeeper

Comment: Java version is 17 installed on windows10 OS.

Comment: And your JAVA_HOME variable? Contains spaces, or not?

Comment: JAVA_HOME set as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 . it has space

Comment: That's known to cause issues. Reinstall Java to C drive, as well. Or else switch to use WSL2, or Docker